# Точка после воскл. знака в двухпряморечном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно? Нужна точка?

> «Мой дипломат, кстати, недавно-таки, — начал кот Борис, — говорил о вашем змие. Он мне сказал: „Этот змий — ужас!“» Потом Борис понял, что, это сказав, он забыл, что змий-то... сзади!

> «Мой дипломат, кстати, недавно-таки, — начал кот Борис, — говорил о вашем змие. Он мне сказал: „Этот змий — ужас!“». Потом Борис понял, что, это сказав, он забыл, что змий-то... сзади!

Comment: Хороший вопрос, плюс от меня.

Comment: Почему хороший? Это два разных предложения, а не одно. Оформление по обычным правилам. Точка не нужна.

Comment: Я, чтобы вы понимали, как там всё, кое-что добавил. Там две прямые речи. Неужели один восклицательный знак **две** точки съест?

Comment: @Sharon Может, тогда ответите на него?)

Comment: Не, лучше вы...)

Comment: @Sharon Я не буду сильно уверен в ответе, да и обосновать его непросто. Вы написали, что не нужна, — следовательно, вы знаете. Поэтому вам и говорю) Кстати, вы почему-то часто отвечаете после того, как я отвечу, а до меня не отвечаете))

Comment: Ага, так удобнее, но это касается не только вас. Мне нравится второй номер, это как в спорте. Пусть сначала все выступят,  а я уж в заключение. Так что подождем))